# Where is my /tmp mounted?

Tags: mount, partition, block-device

```
$ df /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root      480589544 42607368 413546516  10% /

$ ls /dev/root
ls: cannot access /dev/root: No such file or directory
```

I wanted to check if my default Debian installation places `/tmp` in RAM or on the disk, but now am completely confused. Why would a non-existing device be reported as a filesystem type? What doe "mounted on /" mean?

Here is the output of `mount`:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=811520k,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=1013960,mode=755)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=1623020k)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
none_debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=12k)
cgmfs on /run/cgmanager/fs type tmpfs (rw,relatime,size=100k,mode=755)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,release_agent=/run/cgmanager/agents/cgm-release-agent.systemd,name=systemd)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=811520k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
```

Comment: The output seems very spartan. Would you please post the output of the `mount` command?

Comment: `/tmp` is a mount point.  The question you mean to ask is "What partition/device is mounted on /tmp?"

Comment: And phrasing it that way (I think) clarifies your confusion.    `/dev/root` is the device mounted at the root of the filesystem (`/`)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the output is as above, it's on the hard disk. You can get `/dev/root` by looking at the kernel commandline:

```
$ cat /proc/cmdline | grep root
BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-32-generic root=UUID=0cde5cf9-b15d-4369-b3b1-4405204fd9ff ro
```

So `/dev/root` is equivalent to the partition with the UUID printed above; your's will differ. To look this UUID up, use

```
$ sudo blkid
/dev/sda1: UUID="0cde5cf9-b15d-4369-b3b1-4405204fd9ff" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="37bc6a9c-a27f-43dc-a485-5fb1830e1e42" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="177c3cec-5612-44a7-9716-4dcba27c69f9" TYPE="ext4"
```

As you can see, the matching partition is `/dev/sda1`. So your `/tmp` is on the hard disk. Another giveaway in the output of `df` is the mountpoint `/`. If you mounted `/tmp` in the RAM, you'd instead get

```
$ df /tmp
Filesystem     1K-blocks  Used Available Use% Mounted on
tmpfs            3640904    20   3640884   1% /tmp
```

Answer (score 11):

The output of `df /tmp` gives the answer: the “Mounted on” column lists `/`, so `/tmp` is part of the filesystem that's mounted on `/`, i.e. the root filesystem. It is not a separate filesystem.

To be more accurate, you should run `df /tmp/`: if `/tmp` is a symbolic link, then `df /tmp` lists information about the location of the symbolic link, whereas `df /tmp/` lists information about the target directory.

The mention of `/dev/root` in the device column is due to its being listed in `/etc/mtab`. You can find the real device by looking in `/proc/mounts` with `</proc/mounts awk '$2 == "/" {print $1}'` or `findmnt /`.

Comment: +1 for `df /tmp` and `findmnt /`.

Answer (score 0):

`df /path/to/target` shows which filesystem contains the folder target, bytes total, bytes used, percentage available and the mount point.

In the example documented in this question, the folder `/tmp/` is located within the filesystem labeled `root`, which is on the block device `/dev/sda1`.

`mount | grep target` will show any filesystems containing the name target as listed in `/etc/mtab`.  If the target folder is not a separate filesystem, mount will not directly give you accurate information.

However, to know what device contains `/tmp/`, use `df` to get the filesystem name, (`/dev/root`), and the mount point, (`/`), and then search the output of `mount` to find the device or mount point and determine what block device holds that filesystem.

It is important to distinguish between device and filesystem because there is not always a 1:1 correlation.  The block device can be partitioned and each partition will have a filesystem.  Each partition can have a different type of filesystem. Each partition its own unique name and UUID and can have aliases.

Answer (score -2):

To check this, `mount` is more appropriate. You can try it, and grep its output on 'tmp'

**Ex**:

```
$  mount | grep tmp
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs ...
```

Here it says that my partition `/dev/shm` is mounted with **tmpfs** (temporary file storage, i.e. in RAM). If your partition isn't mounted with tmpfs then it's not in volatile memory.

Comment: I was expecting to see `tmpfs on /tmp`.

Comment: On the contrary, `df` gives the information directly, whereas `mount | grep` does not give the information reliably (it would miss cases where `/tmp` is a symbolic link, and it wouldn't work for something like `/var/tmp` since either `/var` or `/var/tmp` could be a mount point).

Comment: `mount` basically prints the contents of the mtab file (`/etc/mtab`).  This shows only mounted filesystems.  If the target folder is not a separate filesystem, you will not find it using mount.  However, if you use `df /path/to/target`, it will positively tell you which block device contains the target folder, and where that device is mounted.  You can then use `mount` or other tools to determine what type of filesystem it is and other information.  In OP's example, your suggestion will not show where the /tmp/ folder is mounted, since his /tmp/ is not a separate filesystem, but part of `/`.